# My PowerShell isn't working when I try to make a function with multiple parameters

Tags: powershell, parameters

I'm trying to make a PowerShell function that will multiply the two given parameters. When I add the parameters, I get this error: `Missing argument in parameter list.PowerShell`  Also I've tried to use PowerShell ISE, same error. Here is my code: `function multiply { params ( 1,2 ) return 1 * 2 } $var1`
I am looking for an answer. Please help!

Comment: have you read the help on functions? have you looked at the code snippets in the ISE - especially the basic function snippet? ///// your code - as posted - does not give the error you show. instead, i get `params : The term 'params' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`.

Answer (score 1):

There are tho ways: Simple and extended declaration

```
Function Multiply1
{
    [CMDLetBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        [Int]$A,
        [Parameter(Position=1)]
        [Int]$B
        )
    return $A * $B
}


Function Multiply2($A, $B)
{
    return $A * $B
}
```

Same for calls:

```
Multiply1 -A 2 -B 3
Multiply2 2 3
```

Google `powershell about_functions` and `powershell about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters` for detailed info about function declarations.

Comment: Nice, but what you call _extended_ should be called _advanced_, and you probable meant to reference [`about_Functions_Advanced`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced)  too.